# Mapping with conditions

Tags: solidity

Here is my structure

```
struct userDetails{
  address wallAdd;
  uint32 isUser;
  uint32 isAdmin;
 }
```

I have to map records where isUser =1 only;

Comment: Can you explain with an example what's the purpose?

Comment: In my struct I have to filter only those records which are users and then I will send some rewards to them

Comment: A mapping alone won't work for that, since they can't be iterated, having an index to the entries should help with that.

Comment: Can you modify and post some code?

Comment: The first answer from this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity, has an example of mapping with index.